# R -RMySQL- how to save more sql queries to file?

Tags: r, rmysql

I do some data analysis in R. On end of script I want save my results to file. I know there is more options how to do it, but they don't work properly. When I try `sink()` it works but it give me :

```
<MySQLResult:1,5,1>
         host logname user                time                                                                       request_fline status
1 142.4.5.115      -    -  2018-01-03 12:08:58  GET /phpmyadmin?</script><script>alert('<!--VAIBS-->');</script><script> HTTP/1.1     400
                                                                size_varchar referer agent     ip_adress size_int cookie time_microsec filename
1  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0    445      -  142.4.5.115       445     -            159        -
  request_protocol keepalive request_method contents_of_foobar contents_of_notefoobar port child_id
<MySQLResult:1,5,1>
 [1] host                   logname                user                   time                   request_fline          status                
 [7] size_varchar           referer                agent                  ip_adress              size_int               cookie                     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

which is totally unusable because I cant export that type of data. If I try `write.table` it give file with one row which is possible read but after one row R skript and give me error : `Error in isOpen(file, "w") : invalid connection` and when I try `write.csv` result is same. And when I try `lapply` it give me just empty file.

There is my code :

```
fileConn<-file("outputX.txt")
fileCon2<-file("outputX.csv")
sink("outputQuery.txt")
for (i in 1:length(awq)){
  sql <- paste("SELECT * FROM mtable ORDER BY cookie LIMIT ", awq[i], ",1")
  nb <- dbGetQuery(mydb, sql)
  print (nb)
  write.table(nb, file = fileConn, append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = " ", eol = "\n", na = "NA", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
  write.csv(nb, file = fileCon2,row.names=FALSE, sep="  ")
  lapply(nb, write, fileConn, append=TRUE, ncolumns=7)
  writeLines(unlist(lapply(nb, paste, collapse=" ")))
}
sink()
close(fileConn)
close(fileCon2)
```

I am new in R, so I don't know what else should I try.What I want is 1 file where data will be print in form which is easy to read and export. For example tike this :

```
142.4.5.115  -   -  2018-01-03 12:08:58  GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1  400  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0  445  -  142.4.5.115  445  -  145 -  HTTP/1.1  0  GET   -   -  80 7216  ?/><!--VAIBS-->   GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1   -  0  /phpmyadmin   -  354 0
142.4.5.115  -   -  2018-01-03 12:10:23  GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1  400  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0  445  -  142.4.5.115  445  -  145 -  HTTP/1.1  0  GET   -   -  80 7216  ?/><!--VAIBS-->   GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1   -  0  /phpmyadmin   -  354 0
142.4.5.115  -   -  2018-01-03 12:12:41  GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1  400  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0  445  -  142.4.5.115  445  -  145 -  HTTP/1.1  0  GET   -   -  80 7216  ?/><!--VAIBS-->   GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1   -  0  /phpmyadmin   -  354 0
142.4.5.115  -   -  2018-01-03 12:15:29  GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1  400  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0  445  -  142.4.5.115  445  -  145 -  HTTP/1.1  0  GET   -   -  80 7216  ?/><!--VAIBS-->   GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1   -  0  /phpmyadmin   -  354 0
```

or this :

```
host,logname,user,time, request_fline status,size_varchar,referer agent,ip_adress,size_int,cookie,time_microsec,filename,request_protocol,keepalive,request_method,contents_of_foobar,contents_of_notefoobar port child_id
1 142.4.5.115  -   -  2018-01-03 12:08:58  GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1  400  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0  445  -  142.4.5.115  445  -  145 -  HTTP/1.1  0  GET   -   -  80 7216  ?/><!--VAIBS-->   GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1   -  0  /phpmyadmin   -  354 0
2 142.4.5.115  -   -  2018-01-03 12:10:23  GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1  400  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0  445  -  142.4.5.115  445  -  145 -  HTTP/1.1  0  GET   -   -  80 7216  ?/><!--VAIBS-->   GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1   -  0  /phpmyadmin   -  354 0
3 142.4.5.115  -   -  2018-01-03 12:12:41  GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1  400  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0  445  -  142.4.5.115  445  -  145 -  HTTP/1.1  0  GET   -   -  80 7216  ?/><!--VAIBS-->   GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1   -  0  /phpmyadmin   -  354 0
4 142.4.5.115  -   -  2018-01-03 12:15:29  GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1  400  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0  445  -  142.4.5.115  445  -  145 -  HTTP/1.1  0  GET   -   -  80 7216  ?/><!--VAIBS-->   GET /phpmyadmin?/><!--VAIBS--> HTTP/1.1   -  0  /phpmyadmin   -  354 0
```

or something similar.  Best of all, will be some help how to write `write.table` in loop without error. But I will welcome any functional solution. Best what I have is :

```
sql <- paste("SELECT * FROM idsaccess ORDER BY cookie LIMIT ", awq[1], ",1")
nb <- dbGetQuery(mydb, sql)
write.table(nb, file = fileConn, append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = " ", eol = "\n", na = "NA", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
fileConn<-file("outputX1.txt")
sql <- paste("SELECT * FROM idsaccess ORDER BY cookie LIMIT ", awq[2], ",1")
nb <- dbGetQuery(mydb, sql)
write.table(nb, file = fileConn, append = true, quote = FALSE, sep = " ", eol = "\n", na = "NA", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

But this give every query to own file. And I don't want have every query in own file. Any help ?

Comment: I don't want print dataframe to file. I just need that raw data in dataframe. Well I dont want export each query to own file because I have python skript which will be work with these file. So it will be simplies if I will have just one file.

Comment: I edit the question and I hope it is now more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply concatenate all query dataframes into **one** large dataframe since they all share same structure, and then output to file in **one** call which is really the typical way to use `write.table` or its wrapper, `write.csv`:

Specifically, turn `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(awq)){
  sql <- paste("SELECT * FROM mtable ORDER BY cookie LIMIT ", awq[i], ",1")
  nb <- dbGetQuery(mydb, sql)
}
```

Into `lapply` for a list of dataframes:

```
df_list <- lapply(1:length(awq), function(i) {
  sql <- paste0("SELECT * FROM mtable ORDER BY cookie LIMIT ", awq[i], ",1")
  nb <- dbGetQuery(mydb, sql)
})
```

Then, row bind with `do.call` to stack all dfs into a single dataframe and output to file:

```
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)

write.table(final_df, file = "outputX.txt", append = true, quote = FALSE, sep = " ", 
            eol = "\n", na = "NA", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```