# R - RMysql - could not run statement: memory exhausted

Tags: r, rmysql

I have R script for data analysis. I try it on 6 different tables from my mysql database. On 5 of them script works fine. But on last table it don't wont work. There is part of my code :

```
sql <- ""
#write union select for just one access to database which will optimize code 
for (i in 2:length(awq)-1){
  num <- awq[i]-1
  sql <- paste(sql, "(SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT ", num, ",1) UNION ")
}
sql <- paste(sql, "(SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT ", awq[length(awq)-1], ",1)")

#database query
nb <- dbGetQuery(mydb, sql)
```

My mysql table where script don't work have 21 676 rows. My other tables have under 20 000 rows and with them script work. If it don't work work it give me this error :

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: memory exhausted near '1) UNION  (SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT  14107 ,1) UNION  (SELECT * FROM mytabl' at line 1
```

I understood there is memory problem. But how to solve it ? I don't want delete rows from my table. Is there another way ?

Comment: What is the length of *awq*?

Comment: it can be anything from 100 to 10 000, if script want pull out half of table

Comment: Up to 10,000 `UNION` calls! Certainly may reach allowable memory limit in your MySQL settings. Consider [list of R dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618238/1422451) like the answer to your last question instead of many `UNION`.

Comment: thank you. I had no idea that problem could be in UNION.

Comment: It's not just `UNION`. You are creating a very large singular query. The default max size of one query is the `max_allowed_packet` for MySQL at 1048576 or 1 MB. Plus you must think of the RAM of your server to process such queries. Imagine 10,000 virtual tables!